# shell_exec doesn't work properly on windows

Tags: php, r, command-line, exec, shell-exec

When I write this script on the command prompt, it works properly :

```
R CMD BATCH test.R
```

But, when I'm trying to execute this code in php on windows with :

```
shell_exec(R CMD BATCH test.R)
```

It gives me a error :  "Error in library(raster) : packages 'raster' was not found"
This has no sense because it does work on unix !

Comment: that error is from r? install the raster library for r.

Comment: the library is already installed and my script works when I type it in command prompt

Comment: try setting any path information for r.  it sounds like a path issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple possiblities:

1. raster package is not installed
2. PHP PATH when calling shell_exec has different environment variables set so it is not loading the right libs (try setting R_LIBS to fix it).
3. Try using an absolute path to r instead of a relative one.

for R_LIBS mentioned above: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html

> By default R_LIBS is unset, and R_LIBS_USER is set to directory ‘R/R.version$platform-library/x.y’ of the home directory (or ‘Library/R/x.y/library’ for CRAN OS X builds), for R x.y.z.

Example from their [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html):

```
"path_to_R\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" HOME=p:/ R_LIBS=p:/myRlib
```

Comment: If it would be because of the library, this would not work when I do it without using php

Comment: how about a workaround: try creating a batch file that contains the command you want to run then use php's shell_exec to call the batch file

Comment: Actually you were true !! thanks you very much :) I did install the library though the shell_exec and it works,